# Check if url has specific string in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I couldn't figure this out

In this code I need to check if the url has http or not

```
for link in links:
    if "http" in link.get("href"):
        print("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))
```

When running I got this error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

How can I fix that?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you share what is in links?

Comment: Check the 'links'. Probably it should be a list

Comment: Thanks for replies .. `links = soup.find_all("a")`

Comment: Please provide a stack trace.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stack trace' .. forgive me as I am totally a beginner

Comment: Can anyone tell me what's stack trace please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess a little bit what exactly your context was. But this might help you.

You can check if something is None by "if var is None:" and continuing the loop.

But my recommendation is to start with basic tutorials instead of jumping right into some concrete tasks... this might be easier for you :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

website = """#INSERT_HTML_CODE""" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')

p = re.compile("https://")
soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')

soup_links = soup.find_all("a")
print(len(soup_links))

counter = 0

for link in soup_links:
    if link is None: # <---- Handle None value with continuing the loop
        continue

    if p.match(link.get("href", "")) is not None: # <--- Handle link element, if https is in href String.
        # If href is not existing. .get() returns "" and nothing is broken
        print("HTTPS found")
        print("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.string) )
        print("")
        counter = counter + 1

print(counter)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your guess is perfect and that is exactly what I was searching for But when testing I got all the links .. I just need the links with http in its string

Comment: @YasserKhalil I updated my code snippet and used regex instead of string.find... Hope this works for you as well! My example works pretty good now.

Comment: That's perfect now. Thank you very much for great help

Comment: You're welcome! Have a great evening! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can just try using `string.find`.

But it seems like your problem is that `link.get("href")` returned None.

Your link probably has no `"href"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you provide me with the code of how to use find ? And what if some elements has None as you mentioned, how to deal with that?